# Constructing sets $D$ and $E$ such that $E$ is the union of countably many nowhere dense sets.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, baire-category

I am trying to solve the following question: "construct sets $D$ and $E$ such that $D \cap E = \emptyset, D \cup E = R, \mu^{*}(D) = 0$, and $E$ is the union of countably many nowhere dense sets".

I wasn't sure if this would be a proof around pure construction based on definitions of nowhere dense sets, or if I would use something else (induction perhaps?). Would appreciate any leads on how to get started!

Thanks!

Comment: A lot more context is needed. For example, is ${\mu}^*$ a $G_{\delta}$-regular outer measure that is zero on singletons? Are singletons nowhere dense in your underlying space? (If this is Lebesgue outer measure and you're in ${\mathbb R}^n,$ then these questions along with consideration of a countable dense subset is a big hint.)

Comment: Theorem 1.6  in Measure and Category by Oxtoby has a construction of such sets when $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming we're in a "nice" space with a "nice" measure (it works for Lebesgue measure in $\Bbb R^n$ e.g.):

Let $Q$ be a countable dense subset of $X$. As $Q$ is countable, $\mu(Q)=0$. So by regularity of the measure (this can easily be made explicit for Lebesgue measure) we can find open subsets $O_n$ so that $Q \subseteq O_n$ and $\mu(O_n) < \frac1n$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$. Then $D= \bigcap_n O_n$ also obeys $\mu(D)=0$, and as $D$ is a dense $G_\delta$, $E:= X\setminus D$ is a union of countably many nowhere dense sets. Done.